# Gerrit project not replicating to bitbucket, ERROR: channel is not opened

Tags: git, bitbucket, replication, gerrit, jsch

One of our Gerrit projects stopped working after a certain date with the following error:

Error from the Gerrit logs /var/gerrit/logs/error_log:[2016-07-29 17:59:51,676]

> ERROR
>   com.googlesource.gerrit.plugins.replication.ReplicationQueue : **Cannot
>   replicate to git@bitbucket.org:company/product.git**
>   org.eclipse.jgit.errors.TransportException:
>   git@bitbucket.org:company/product.git: **channel is not opened.** at
>   org.eclipse.jgit.transport.JschSession$JschProcess.(JschSession.java:154)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.jgit.transport.JschSession$JschProcess.(JschSession.java:118)
>   at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.JschSession.exec(JschSession.java:91) at
>   org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportGitSsh$SshPushConnection.(TransportGitSsh.java:306)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportGitSsh.openPush(TransportGitSsh.java:152)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.jgit.transport.PushProcess.execute(PushProcess.java:154)
>   at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.Transport.push(Transport.java:1167) at
>   org.eclipse.jgit.transport.Transport.push(Transport.java:1213) at
>   com.googlesource.gerrit.plugins.replication.PushOne.pushVia(PushOne.java:307)
>   at
>   com.googlesource.gerrit.plugins.replication.PushOne.runImpl(PushOne.java:252)
>   at
>   com.googlesource.gerrit.plugins.replication.PushOne.runPushOperation(PushOne.java:207)
>   at
>   com.googlesource.gerrit.plugins.replication.PushOne.access$000(PushOne.java:71)
>   at
>   com.googlesource.gerrit.plugins.replication.PushOne$1.call(PushOne.java:186)
>   at
>   com.googlesource.gerrit.plugins.replication.PushOne$1.call(PushOne.java:183)
>   at
>   com.google.gerrit.server.util.RequestScopePropagator$5.call(RequestScopePropagator.java:222)
>   at
>   com.google.gerrit.server.util.RequestScopePropagator$4.call(RequestScopePropagator.java:201)
>   at
>   com.google.gerrit.server.git.PerThreadRequestScope$Propagator$1.call(PerThreadRequestScope.java:75)
>   at
>   com.googlesource.gerrit.plugins.replication.PushOne.run(PushOne.java:183)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
>   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:292)
>   at com.google.gerrit.server.git.WorkQueue$Task.run(WorkQueue.java:337)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   **com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: channel is not opened.** at
>   com.jcraft.jsch.Channel.connect(Channel.java:197) at
>   org.eclipse.jgit.transport.JschSession$JschProcess.(JschSession.java:150)
>   ... 25 more

Our Gerrit version is 2.6.1 installed on CentOS release 6.8 in AWS.

My gerrit replication configuration is:

```
[remote "bitbucket"]
    url = git@bitbucket.org:qpidhealth/${name}.git
    push = +refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*
    push = +refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*
    threads = 2
    authGroup = Replication
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: waiting for answers from both Atlassian: https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/39449158/cant-repo-sync-anymore and Gerrit group: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/repo-discuss/oa2Dy0wpXhw.  Crickets so far.

Answer (score 2):

This is the known issue. This problem is caused by SSH used under the hood by Git. Bitbucket disabled SSH multiplexing as a result we are getting this error. There are some suggested solutions but none of them work for me. https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/Can-t-repo-sync-anymore/qaq-p/354231

So I decided to try HTTPS and it works.

First of all you need to add a remote section to the `replication.config` file

```
[remote "bitbucket"]
    url = https://USER@bitbucket.org/USER/${name}.git
    push = +refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*
    push = +refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*
    mirror = true
    projects = NameOfYourProject
    replicateOnStartup = true
    replicatePermissions = false
```

Secondly, set your Bitbucket credentials in the `etc/secure.config` file as follows

```
[remote "bitbucket"]
    password = yourBitbucketPassword
```

And now reload the plugin settings and try to replicate a repository.

I have written an article about setting up replication over HTTPS, please refer to it to get more details about the configuration process. 
https://crosp.net/blog/administration/devops/setting-gerrit-bitbucket-replication-https/

Comment: Than you @CROSP, I've given up on the issue and implemented my own solution (cost effective). I'll try the replication plugin again soon after I upgrade Gerrit.

Comment: @RossAribi ,  you are welcome, if you have any problems setting up it please feel free to contact me

Answer (score -1):

I've experienced a related (not sure how close) issue just coming across your question by googling for "org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.TransportException channel is not opened", which also pointed me to:

- https://ecosystem.atlassian.net/browse/MJF-281
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-46052

Sorry, the following is not a definite answer at all, but, by just quickly glancing at those pointers it seemed to me this was an issue with Bitbucket and not with my code. In fact, I just reran my application and it successfully completed the step that was previously causing the TransportException.  So, as a workaround to better handle this potential issue again, I'm planning on catching the exception and retrying one or two more times (with some wait in between).

Comment: Thank you Carueda. Even Bitbucket support couldn't help. I've implemented my own replication solution for now. I'll try the replication plugin again after I upgrade Gerrit. That could be a factor.

Comment: Sure ross-aribi, glad you found it useful.  Yeah, unfortunately Bitbucket/Atlassian support sometimes leaves one a bit frustrated; this was a case where I resorted to this workaround.